# Access to Simperium user account database or bucket

Tags: simperium

Is there a Simperium API to retrieve a list of all usernames, user IDs, and/or map between the two?  (Obviously the admin key would be required).

I want to store some information per-user.  Is there a way to store it in a bucket where user accounts live?  Or should I create a separate bucket for this info?

I've read the reference and all I see is that 'create' and 'authorize' will return the user ID.  Some API calls take username.  It would seem my user account info should be keyed by userID since that's guaranteed not to change, whereas the username can change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that, at least for the time being, there is no API to list usernames / id's per Simperium App.

Please, bear in mind that even if you setup a Shared Bucket, it would not be a good idea to let every client put data there (because, potentially, all of your users will get notified of every single change made there).

One possible alternative would be to write a "Global Listener", which could allow you to keep a replica of everything that happens in your Simperium App. You can find more about it [here](http://simperium.com/tutorials/simpletodo-python/).